# Torrent doesn't upload

Tags: 14.04, networking, transmission, torrent-client

I have a laptop which has windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04LTS installed. Windows seeds the torrent back but Ubuntu doesn't. I have tried several client on Ubuntu but I got the same issue. It can Download the torrent but as soon as it downloaded it just spots and keep telling that connected peers 0/0. Can anybodí help me?

Comment: Are you running a firewall in Ubuntu?

Comment: How do I check it?

Comment: A common firewall in Ubuntu is ufw - you could try `sudo ufw status` to determine if the firewall is active.

Comment: Status: inactive

Comment: Which torrent client are you running?

Comment: transmission client

Comment: i always find transmission to be slower than qBittorent(try by this)

Answer (score 0):

You need to open **port** on your modem/router. This is usually done by your client (which one ?) automatically with **UPnP**. If not, you need to do it yourself. Check the doc of your *torrent client*.

For *transmission*, it's in edit/preferences/network and check "use UPnP or NAT-PMP on the router". this should be the default.

Edit:
You could check if the port is open in transmisssion. Just click the "Check the port button". It should be ok from what you said.

Comment: UPnP is enabled on my router and in the transmission cluent as well

Comment: The default port for `transmission` is 9091 - you should check that your router is passing this through to your computer.